# HighStock.js flags tooltip box formatting

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HighStock.js library and I'm trying to display the flags and their tooltips.

Everything works well, except the tooltip box is too wide that it goes outside of the chart area.[image]

How do I format the box so that its width is set?

I tried the following

```
  plotOptions:
    flags:
      useHTML:true
      tooltip:
        followPointer:true
        pointFormat:"<div style='width:200px;'>{point.text}</div>"
```

But nothing changes.

Comment: I posted an answer but deleted it because the tooltip behaved wierdly with different values of the `style` property. Anyway, can you post a jsfiddle of your chart?

Answer (score 0):

You can set more CSS styles like `white-space: pre-wrap`, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/9Pxka/6/